# Prove that this transformation of a stochastic matrix (or markov chain) is still a stochastic matrix (or markov chain)

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Assume to have an $N \times N$ stochastic matrix $W$, where $\sum_j w_{ij} = 1$ and $w_{ij}$ is a generic element on row $i$ column $j$ of the matrix $W$. Moreover you have the following two $N \times N$ matrices:

\begin{equation}
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}
 A =
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1-\alpha_{1} & 1-\alpha_{1} & 1-\alpha_{1} & ... & 1-\alpha_{1}\\
  1-\alpha_{2} &  &  &  & \vdots \\
   1-\alpha_{3} &  &  &  & \vdots  \\
  \vdots &  &  &  &  \vdots \\
   1-\alpha_{N} & ... & ... & ... & 1-\alpha_{N}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \;.
  \end{equation}

and 
 \begin{equation}
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}
 B =
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \alpha_{1} & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{3} & ... & \alpha_{N}\\
  \alpha_{1} &  &  &  & \vdots \\
   \alpha_{1} &  &  &  & \vdots  \\
  \vdots &  &  &  &  \vdots \\
   \alpha_{1} & ... & ... & ... & \alpha_{N}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \;.
  \end{equation}

where $0<\alpha_i<1 \; \forall i$. 
I need to prove that the matrix 
\begin{equation}
C = B \circ (I - A \circ W)^{-1}
\end{equation}
where $\circ$ is the hadamard product, is also a stochastic matrix.

Do you have hint? I am getting crazy over this! 
Thank you very much!

J.

Comment: Update. I have found the following proposition: 

"Let {Xn} be a Markov chain. If g is a one-to-one Borel function, then {g(Xn)} is also a Markov chain".  

Is it possible to show that the transformation of $W$ described above is a one-to-one Borel function? I am not an expert mathematician. 

Thank you!

Comment: The above expression for ${\bf C}$ can also be translated into using normal matrix product as :
$$
{\bf C} = \left( {{\bf I} - \left( {{\bf I - D}} \right){\bf W}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf D}
$$
where {\bf D} is the diagonal matrix having $\alpha _{\,n}$ as diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expand the inverse as,
$$(I-A \circ W)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (A\circ W)^k$$
I think that the series is guaranteed to converge for those matrices. 
Then notice that 
$$B=1-A^T$$
Then it can be proved, with some little manipulations, that
$$\sum_j \left[(A\circ W)^{k+1}\right] _{ij} - \left[A^T\circ(A\circ W)^{k}\right] _{ij} =0 $$
In fact one has
$$\sum_j \left[(A\circ W)^{k+1}\right] _{ij} =\sum_j\sum_m \left[(A\circ W)^{k}\right] _{im} \left[A\circ W\right] _{mj} =\sum_m \left[(A\circ W)^{k}\right] _{im} (1-\alpha_m)$$ 
Once you do that it is easy to conclude the proof noticing that the only relevant term of the series is the one with $k=0$, therefore you have 
$$ \sum_j C_{ij} = \sum_j [1\circ I]_{ij} =\sum_j I_{ij} =1 \qquad \forall i$$

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much!